# Including CSS file to JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

Cannot find the correct path for css that must be included to .jsp file.

The css files are in css folder and jsp is in folder "views" as shown in
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F45uA.jpg).
Have tried different paths to include it, but without result.

```
<link href="<c:url value="..." />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="..." rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Could someone give information or correct path from .jsp file ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `WEB-INF` folder is protected by server, you should move `css` & `js` folder to upper level, means `css` & `js` folder should exists in `WebContent` folder directly.
The structure should be like this:

```
-WebContent
 -META-INF
 -WEB-INF
 -css
 -js
```

Comment: Seems logical. The css & js was moved to WebContent folder.
Have tried every path: ../..css/style.css  ;  ././css/style.css  ; css/style.css  and so-on, but nothing has worked so far. In example project the directory is same and there is used css/style.css like relative path starts from WebContent

Comment: The paths are in .jsp file, specifically in <head> and should be correct.

Comment: can you post the **screenshot** that code rendered in browser?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between where files physically exist in project structure and where they are in runtime context is a classic problem (in my experience) with Java.

You could try using:

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

to find out the directory at runtime and use this to build a correct reference to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ./css/yourfilename as the path 
./ means one up the current directory but the best way to do it is using the absolute path there are many advantage of using the absolute paths for example href="http:www.example.com/css/main.css" .

as meantioned by simon the web-inf could also be the problem